# Openrowset operator does not display decimals in some columns

Tags: sql

I have the query:

```
select *
        from 
        openrowset ('msdasql', 'driver={microsoft text driver (*.txt; *.csv)}; 
                  defaultdir=f:\Temp\Presupuesto\Formatos Gasto\;' 
                  ,'select * from menores.csv')
        where cuenta <> ''
```

this query shows me columns with decimals and columns without decimals.

In the Menores.CSV is displayed this way:

[image]

When I run the query it shows me this:

[image]